# Can't start a IOUFlow from CordaShell (cordapp-template tutorial)

Tags: corda

I'm trying to run the IOU cordapp-template but when I start the IOUFlow from the shell I got this error

[image: Corda IOU Flow Error]

If the image isn't readable this is the command I'm providing

```
start IOUFlow arg0: 10, arg1: "CN=NodeB,O=NodeB,L=New York, C=US"
```

And this is the Error I got

```
[iouValue: Int, otherParty: Party]: missing parameter iouValue
```

However my object IOUFlow is correct, any suggestion on how to work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't supply the params as `arg0`, `arg1` etc, but as the names of the parameters themselves.

i.e.

`Mon Jul 31 10:45:54 BST 2017>>> flow start ExampleFlow iouValue: 10, otherParty: "CN=NodeB,O=NodeB,L=New York, C=US"`

It's important to include the space between the `:` and the (e.g.) `10` value for parsing reasons.

Comment: Thanks Richard, worked perfectly. I'm feeling a bit like a noob but hey, need to start from somewhere :D

Comment: Lol - I wouldn't worry about feeling like a noob - it gets a bit easier 18 months down the line especially if you are sitting in the same room as dozens of other Corda developers....

Comment: Note that you only pass the arguments by name in Kotlin. In Java, you have to use `arg0`, `arg1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

change it into

```
start ExampleFlow iouValue: 10, otherParty: "CN=NodeB,O=NodeB,L=New York, C=US"
```

even when you just run the the java example