# cordapp-template-java "No matching constructor found..."

Tags: java, corda

I tried testing the Hello, World! Tutorial example and received the following error:

```
No matching constructor found:
- [arg0: Integer, arg1: Party]: missing parameter arg0
```

This was generated by running the command:

```
start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
```

Please see [here](https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-running.html#interacting-with-the-nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using the command:

```
start IOUFlow arg0: 99, arg1: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400515/cant-start-a-iouflow-from-cordashell-cordapp-template-tutorial#comment77804241_45412519) comment, you're only supposed to pass variables by name when using Kotlin Cordapps. When using Java Cordapps specify arg0, arg1, etc.